# uploading or exporting a large video sucks memory and causes crash...how can I break it up?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdata, avfoundation

I've implemented a way to upload video to youtube, etc. using multipart post, or save a video to the camera roll locally. However, with large videos I get watchdogged due to too large of a memory footprint, because currently I have to put the entire video in memory in order to post it or save it.

What are the steps I could take to break up a large video into manageable chunks?

Comment: Are you using a HTTP library such as ASIHTTPRequest, or are you rolling your own?

Comment: I'm not using ASIHTTPRequest currently.

Comment: I am assuming you are doing this yourself. The only other thing I can think of is to use a memory mapped file. Such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172919/ios-memory-mapped-files-and-low-memory-scenarios)

Comment: Memory mapping looks interesting. Would it work with saving a video to the camera roll?

Comment: That I am not sure of. I am not familiar with saving videos to the camera roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your video to a file and use nsstream to read chunks of the video and send them, you'll have to keep some state to remember what u sent and what's left but it shouldn't be too bad to implement, for example

```
  BOOL done=FALSE;
   NSInputStream *stream=nil;

   NSString *myFile=@"..."; //your file path
   stream=[[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:myFile ];
  while(!done)
  {


   int chunkSize=500000; //500 kb chunks 
   uint8_t buf[chunkSize];
      //reads into the buffer and returns size read
   NSInteger size=[stream read:buf maxLength:chunkSize];

   NSLog(@"read %d bytes)", size);

    NSData * datum=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buf length:size];
      //when we actually read something thats less than our chunk size we are done
   if(size<chunkSize)
     done=TRUE;
   //send data      
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand I can stream the video, but how would this work with the SDK to save it to the Camera Roll?

Comment: Well, if you are downloading  a file, you can append the data to a file as it comes (so you dont keep it all in memory) and then write it to the camera roll...

Comment: I understand. However, my issue primarily lies with the call to save a local file to the camera roll, or to save that local file to the web. Either of those calls will result in the memory crash.

Comment: How are you saving to photo album? To save to photo album you only need the video URL, so not sure why it would be causing you problems...

Comment: Just using the standard ALAssetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum api calls.

Comment: Can u post that code? What crash are you getting when you do that? I been saving pretty big videos to library using ALAssetsLibrary with no issues...