# Memory Swapping and Virtual Memory on iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, virtual-memory

Does `iOS` support memory swapping and virtual memory that automatically runs like Linux?

Comment: Folks putting things on hold NEED TO GET A LIFE. This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Nah it's okay,I already got what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iOS` has virtual memory, but no backing store, so there is no paging in/out from swap memory.

Apple's [About the Virtual Memory System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html) documentation should give you a general idea about how iOS provides virtual memory, however it hasn't been updated since 2013 and doesn't cover newer 64-bit details.

Answer (score 0):

As Petah wrote it does have a virtual memory but it doesn't swap automatically on a backing store, you can [map file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172919/memory-mapped-files-and-low-memory-scenarios) tough.
There are some WWDC videos that face that subject:

- [iOS App performance Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-242/)
- [Optimizing your app performance for multitasking in iPAD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-212/)

And probably the talk again in one WWDC 2011 video.
I don't know why you are asking that, but if it is about about memory occupation concern, there are a lot of techniques to keep it low, file map, respond correctly to memory warnings, purgeable memory, NSCache. I strongly suggest you to watch the second video.