# VM Tracker Swapped memory

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, memory

What is the "Swapped Size" in Xcode VM Tracker instrumentation tool on iOS? Does iOS 10 have swap?

[image: VM Tracker iOS Screenshot]

Comment: iOS doesn't have swapped memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261845/memory-swapping-and-virtual-memory-on-ios

Comment: @SergeyMolyak So what is it then?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the compressed memory, which is how iOS deals with unused pages. Instead of totally moving unused pages from RAM to drive, it compresses them and keeps compressed bytes in RAM. However, one important thing to note is that your app's total memory footprint will still be computed using the UNCOMPRESSED size. The moment you access the page again, it will get decompressed again in RAM. So the "swap size" in all the tools actually refers to the UNCOMPRESSED size of unused pages. On iOS, ultimately your memory footprint = dirty + swap size.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/?time=125

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33674215)

Comment: well my answer wasn't link only :) but i'll edit it to include more info.